# calculation of Kendall-Theil-Sen intercept

Tags: mathematical-statistics

There are two approaches for estimating the Kendall-Theil-Sen intercept b0.

Approach 1
β0 = Median{yi - β1*xi : 1 ≤ i ≤ n}

Approach 2
β0 = Y_median - β1*X_median
where X_median is the median of the x values and
Y_median is the median of the y values

Given Dataset
x   8   26  29  30  32  34  35  36  37  39
y   33  15  26  16  20  32  21  30  29  35

I get the slope 5/6 now using the slope I will calculate the possible intercepts
β0 = 33 - 5/6(8) = 79/3
β0 = 15 - 5/6(26) = -20/3
β0 = 26 - 5/6(29) = 11/6
β0 = 16 - 5/6(30) = -9
β0 = 20 - 5/6(32) = -20/3
β0 = 32 - 5/6(34) = 11/3
β0 = 21 - 5/6(35) = -49/6
β0 = 30 - 5/6(36) = 0
β0 = 29 - 5/6(37) = -11/6
β0 = 35 - 5/6(39) = 5/2
Arranging all these values in ascending order
-9, -49/6, -20/3, -20/3, -11/6, 0, 11/6,  5/2,  11/3,  79/3
Since n = 10 which is even hence
Median= (5^th term + 6^th term)/2 = ((-11/6) + 0) / 2 = -11/12
However the intercept is given as -20/3 so clearly there is something wrong with the calculations but I cant seem to find it. Need Help!

Also if I use method 2 the median of x is 33 and the median of y is 27.5 therefore
β0 = 27.5 - 5/6(33) = 0
which clearly does not match with approach 1 value which is the real answer

Comment: How do you know -20/3 is "the real answer"?  Don't trust what people tell you.  Plot the data and the two lines and judge for yourself which solutions make sense.

Comment: please click on the link. This example was taken from this journal. https://dergipark.org.tr/en/download/article-file/1986084

Comment: Even peer-reviewed journal articles contain errors.

Comment: There's an infinite number of approaches to choosing an intercept to go with a Theil-Sen slope, though perhaps 3 are relatively common; several more have perfectly sensible justifications. [Both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9pRU.png) of the intercept estimates you mention seem to offer pretty sensible fits to these data, though one might ponder if a linear fit makes the best choice of model.

Comment: Dietz lists ten possibilities for intercepts here: http://web.archive.org/web/20190705013611/https://www.stat.ncsu.edu/information/library/mimeo.archive/ISMS_1987_1690R.pdf though naturally that's not exhaustive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RStudio says you were correct, the intercept is indeed -11/12:

```r
> library("RobustLinearReg")
> x = c(8 ,26 ,29 ,30 ,32 ,34 ,35 ,36 ,37 ,39)
> y = c(33 ,15 ,26 ,16 ,20 ,32 ,21 ,30 ,29 ,35)
> theil_sen_regression(y ~ x)$coefficients
(Intercept)           x 
 -0.9166667   0.8333333
```

Comment: Please tell us also (as an eit to the post) from which R package is `theil_sen_regression`.  U usefull way to tell it is in the code use `PACKAGE_NAME::theil_sen_regression`

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sure.

Comment: can you provide the link of the RStudio compiler you used to get these answers

Comment: RStudio had nothing to do with this calculation, which was performed by `R`.  See https://cran.r-project.org/.